# UILabel text alignment right

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I want that my text should be align right.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"lisn"];
cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"lisn"] autorelease];
CGSize  textSize = { 210.0, 10000.0 };
CGSize size = [[gMessageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UILabel *lisnerMessage=[[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
lisnerMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[lisnerMessage setFrame:CGRectMake(75 ,20,size.width + 5,size.height+2)];
lisnerMessage.numberOfLines=0;
lisnerMessage.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
lisnerMessage.text=[gMessageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lisnerMessage];
return cell
}
```

but my text is not align right Please Help

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but a comment on the logic.  Are you sure you want to add an extra label to your cell every time the table is refreshed?

Comment: @PhillipMills:for each cell i have different text,not extra text in that cell

Comment: Unless there is code somewhere that removes old labels from your cells, what you posted will always add one more label every time it's called for a specific index path.

Comment: @PhillipMills:yes what i am trying?

Answer (score 14):

Because you are using sizeWithFont and then setting your frame to that size, your text is aligned right. Try added a background color of light gray to your label to see what I'm talking about. Your label should be set to the same size as your table cell and allow the text to flow inside it. Then it will align to the right.

**Update with sample**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"lisn"];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"lisn"];

    UILabel *lisnerMessage = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lisnerMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [lisnerMessage setFrame:cell.frame];
    lisnerMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
    lisnerMessage.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    lisnerMessage.text = [gMessageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lisnerMessage];

    return cell
}
```

Comment: :can you please elaborate or put some code regarding your answer. It wiil be very helpfull for me

Comment: Yes, the trick with the different background colour is a good one. It will help Alok understanding what happens. Using sizeWithFont is ok in principle, but I would not use size.with for the frame. Use [lisnerMessage setFrame:CGRectMake(75 , 20, textSize.width + 5, size.height+2)]; instead.

Comment: I've edited your code with a crude example of the changes needed. I didn't test it in Xcode but thats the idea. just rebuild your logic accordingly.

Comment: @RyanPoolos:you are right the text is align right in the cell but actually i want that the my text align right within that fram what i have used.

Comment: It will be aligned in whatever the frame of your label is.

Comment: @RyanPoolos: Actually when i am using [lisnerMessage setFrame:CGRectMake(75 ,20,size.width + 5,size.height+2)]; then the text is not align right. but when i am using [lisnerMessage setFrame:CGRectMake(75 ,20,200,100)]; then the text is align right. So is there problem with size.width & size.height...

Comment: is `size.width + 5 = 200`? and `size.height + 2 = 100`?

Comment: UITextAlignmentRight is deprecated. Use: NSTextAlignmentRight

Answer (score 9):

Right alignment for label

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have fix my problem. I was doing small mistake

```
[lisnerMessage setFrame:CGRectMake(75 ,20,size.width + 5,size.height+2)];
```

I just remove `size.width` and give my specific coordinate 200 after that the text is align right.

```
[lisnerMessage setFrame:CGRectMake(75 ,20,200,size.height+2)];
```

Thanks all for your response

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the label in interface builder/storyboard and select the "align right" option? Then connect it as a property named lisnerMessage and 
`lisnerMessage.text=[gMessageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
That would significantly cut down on how much code you're writing and definitely work.